# Key value mapping in java hash map

Tags: java

I diged into java class files and found that an entry class is implemented to insert the key and value into a hash map.

But i was not able to find how a key is mapped to its corresponding object.

It would be great if anybody helps out in this

Thanks 
Shasi Sekar

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`put(key, value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method of your map.

The `key` of the Object you want to insert in a `HashMap` is generated thanks to the [`hashcode()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode%28%29) method.

You should read this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) explaining the basics of maps.